# Prevent pip from manipulating other modules

Tags: python, pip

I installed pyswarm package using pip (pip install pyswarm).
The problem is that this upgrades my numpy to version 1.14.xx which is something that I really don't want.
Is there anyway to install python package without letting it manipulate other already installed packages?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is nothing much you can do because the pyswarm is dependent on the specific version of numpy.

[One Solution is you can use virtualenv to create separate python environment](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/)

Comment: that solution implies you don't want to use the specific numpy and pyswarm in the same project :/ Alternatively you can download the specific version of numpy and vendor it into your project and reference that code directly, then install pyswarm with pip and have it use its own numpy dependency?

Comment: The thing is I have no problem using it when i reinstall back to my original version by removing the changed numpy. Although the process is trivial, I was just wondering if I could somehow force pip to install only the specific package and leave the dependent ones alone...

Comment: @CodyChung are you not using pyswarm and the specific numpy in the same project? if so you should definitely go with the virtualenv solution

Comment: Pip allows you to download and satisfy all the dependency in your case you can download the python file for pyswarm from pypi repo and install it manually but then again you have to make sure nothing breaks because of different dependency

Comment: Author of Pyswarms here. This reply is two years late but just want to let you know that I relaxed the dependency requirements of PySwarms last 2019. If anyone encountered this same problem again, just let me know at https://github.com/ljvmiranda921/pyswarms

Answer (score 0):

You can use [virutalenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to create separate python environments for you projects so that it versions of the libraries won't conflict between the project. I recommend using [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) which is the combination of pip and virtualenv. It is very easy to easy and has powerful features.